# How to change view in xamarin.ios app when network is available?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to change view in iOS app if internet is available then some view will be visible otherwise not and also in middle if internet connectivity went then view should also change  according to condition? Let's say I have one view `abc`, I want to show this view when internet is available and when internet is not available then don't show view `abc`.

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you have already tried, and also check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect if internet is working, then using Hidden property should make it.

Comment: yes that i am managing but problem is that if view is present and in middle internet went then how to check ??

Comment: I don't know on iOS, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[Reachability.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs)** to detect the connection of the Internet. When your Internet connection updates, it will notice you and you can update the visible status of the view.

You can detect the Internet connection like this:

```
       Reachability.ReachabilityChanged += UpdateStatus;
```

Update the visible status here:

```
        void UpdateStatus (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Update the visible of your view.
        }
```

To get the **Reachability.cs** file and more information, you can refer to the [Reachability Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ReachabilitySample/).